# Can't deploy web app having EJB component injected

Tags: jsf-2, deployment, ejb-3.1, managed-bean

software used :
1- GlassFish 3.1.2
2- JDK 6.0
3- Eclipse Juno Service Release 1

whenever I try adding my dynamic web app to GlassFish this exception in pop-up window :

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:           
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Lcoreservlets/bean/NumberService;
```

I've tried also looking up the EJB component using InitailContext + JNDI in vain, even so it worked from a plain java project .

I tried GlassFish 3.1.1 as well as a last resort but nothing doing .

May you look over my source code and tell me what goes wrong :

for the starters, my POJI :

```
package coreservlets.bean;
import javax.ejb.*;
@Remote
public interface NumberService {
public double getNumber(double range);
}
```

secondly EJB POJO :

```
package coreservlets.bean;
import javax.ejb.*;
@Stateless(mappedName="NumberCreator")
public class NumberServiceBean implements NumberService {
public double getNumber(double range) {
return(Math.random() * range);
}
}
```

Lastly Managed Bean :

```
package beans;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import coreservlets.bean.NumberService;
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

@EJB private NumberService service;
private Double luckyNumber;
public Double getLuckyNumber() {
    luckyNumber = service.getNumber(Math.random() * 100);
    return luckyNumber;
}   
}
```

Please lend hand sorting out this mess for I've been trying to figure it out for a couple of days so far , Am pretty grateful .

Comment: Look closer at the exception message. The problem is not the `MyBean` class. The problem is the `NumberService` class. The `NoClassDefFoundError` basically means that its `.class` file cannot be found, or at least that the class cannot be loaded by `Class#forName()`. The probable causes for that should now become very obvious enough: a compile error, or not being placed in classpath, or it threw an exception in some `static` field/initializer. You need to edit and improve your question to post details about your `NumberService` class instead of your `MyBean`.

Comment: I noticed the problem regarding NumberService, sir, But It's over me why that happens, however i already added EJB project to my dynamic web project classpath .

Comment: @BalusC Could you slack a moment here please, I backed up my question with more code as you suggested, thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I created the EJb project and the web dynamic project from scratch with the " add project to an EAR " checked, everything is sorted out now .
So everyone happened to see my question, I recommend you to follow my answer, because the exception has nothing to do with the code, It might be eclipse-related bug or so .

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem do not related to Eclipse bug or something like that,when you deploy web project containing  EJB project to glassfish do this:

1. Create your EJB Project
2. Create your Dynamic web project(JSF
   project)
3. Add the EJB Project to JSF Project in the build path
4. create an EAR to unite your two projects

if you want a complete tutorial about this operation see this(http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/05/ejbjsf-master-detail-web-application-in_25.html)